# In-place upgrade of Win7 x64 ENT to Win10 x64 ent

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

The Organization I work for his migrating to windows 10 and some Lenovo X1 Carbon laptops are being upgraded from Windows 7 x64 ent to Windows 10 x64 ent we launch the installer but the option to keep programs and files is greyed out.

At the bottom is a message stating `You can't keep Windows settings, personal files, and apps because you've chosen to install Windows 10 using a different language than you're currently using.`

I can confirm both Windows 7 and the Windows 10 media are of the same language.

Comment: What language is that? Have you asked your organization IT? In my own experience, I've seen warnings like this (though not referencing language) which are meaningless and no applications or files are lost.

Comment: Also English (US) and English (UK), along with dozens of similar variations, are not the same language from the OS' point of view.

Comment: looking at the windows 7 image on the system and the  language on the install media files both are en-us

Comment: Also  previously on a test windows 7 pro image  activated with MAK  the inplace upgrade did work ,  maybe enterprise to enterprise in place upgrade isnt allowed?

Comment: Well you can do in-place upgrades with Enterprise, and the error indicates, the reason the can’t in this case

Comment: resolved my issue , turns out the latest W10 1709 iso contains enterprise, enterprise-n, education, education-n, pro, pro-n  what i had to do is open up the iso in NTlite  delete the versions i dont want, recreate the ISO and now issue is resolved and files and apps can be kept